# WSO2 Governance REGDB

Tags: mysql, wso2, governance-registry, soa-governance, wso2-governance-registry

I have configured my WSO2 Governance repository to MySQL by following the steps in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+to+MySQL.

Is there a document which explains the REGDB schema? For e.g. which table stores the asset's association information and etc.

Thanks in advance.

Rgds,
neo

Answer (score 1):

You can find the major tables like the following, used for mounting the registry and its resources in the documentation available [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Tables+Used+in+Governance+Registry)

```
REG_RESOURCE
REG_CONTENT
REG_RESOURCE_HISTORY
```

Also the detailed steps to setup the registry using MySQL, find here. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Setting+up+MySQL

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have changed the database from H2 to MySQl by following the instructions in the link provided by you earlier.

Comment: However, there are errors cause by the non existence of table 'regdb.idn_claim_dialect' and 'regdb.idp' when starting the server. I found the scripts that create these two tables in the PRODUCT_HOME/dbscripts/identity folder but based on the MYSQL setup instructions, I only executed the mysql.sql script in the dbscripts folder. Besides that, I am also encountering error when tried to list the user and roles in the admin page console. Is these two issues related? Please advise.